# Fail to retrieve data from postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

this is my connection string for connection postgresql database .And using this code I  am able to connect the db

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/Test", "youtube",
                    "1");
```

Then I am using the same code to  retrieve some data .And I get this exception

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: "userdetail" NOT EXIST
  Position: 27
```

which referr this line

```
con=GetDbConn();
```

So mytable name is UserDetail  not userdetail I dont understand why am i getting this exception message

And this is my code

```
public class DbUtils {

    private static final String DB_DRIVER="org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONN="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/Test";
    private static final String DB_USER="youtube";
    private static final String DB_PASS="1";

    public  void  SelectUserDetails() {
        Connection con=null;
        Statement statement;
        String query="select isim,soyisim  from UserDetail";

        try {
            con=GetDbConn();
            statement= con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query);

            while(resultSet.next()){

                String isimM=resultSet.getString("isim");
                String soyisimM=resultSet.getString("soyisim");
                System.out.println("isim :"+soyisimM+" soyisim: "+soyisimM);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    private static Connection GetDbConn() {

          Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);



        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;


    }
}
```

Comment: is the table in the user account or in another schema?

Comment: You don't have a table called `userdetail`. If it is called `UserDetail` (capital U and D), then you need to quote the objectname: `"UserDetail"`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. There is no table `userdetail`. Maybe you created that using double quotes so the table is now called `"UserDetail"` which is a different name. Details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: I have changed database name as userdetail and  owner to postgresql .Then I can connect .Could you please someone explain what was wrong